# Как правильно выполнить sql запрос

Tags: sql

Имеется 3 таблицы:

```
1 клиент
2 продукт
3 заказ
```

Клиент

```
id 
name
```

Продукт

```
id 
productname
```

Заказ

```
id 
clientId 
prdouctId
```

Допустим содержимое таблицы клиент

```
1 Валера
2 Маша
3 Валера
```

Продукт

```
1 Хлеб 
2 Соль
```

Заказ

```
1 1 1 (1 Валера Хлеб)
2 1 2 (2 Валера Соль)
3 2 2 (2 Маша Соль)
4 3 1 (2 Валера Соль)
```

Как мне вывести все товары у клиента clientId  = 1?
Например, чтобы было |Валера| Хлеб| Соль?

Comment: Чтобы одним запросом в одной строке перечислены товары (например, через запятую)? Или в разных строках (записях), а перечислять уже программно будете?

Comment: И кстати, у Вас MySQL или MS SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Правильнее*, с точки зрения принципа разделения логики и представления, будет сделать простую выборку:

```
SELECT `Клиент`.`name`, `Продукт`.`productname`
FROM `Заказ`
LEFT JOIN `Клиент` ON `Заказ`.`clientId` = `Клиент`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `Продукт` ON `Заказ`.`prdouctId` = `Продукт`.`id`
WHERE `Заказ`.`clientId` = 1
```

Так вы получите все строки с продуктами пользователя. Дальше вы сможете представить их в том виде, в котором хотитет и легко поменять это представление, не изменяя сам запрос.

Если же вы хотите получить всё-таки все данные одной строкой, то воспользуйтесь ответом @cheops.

Answer (score 0):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  c.name AS client,
  GROUP_CONCAT(p.productname) AS products
FROM
  clients AS c
LEFT JOIN
  clients_products AS cp
ON
  c.id = cp.clientId
LEFT JOIN
  products AS p
ON
  p.id = cp.prdouctId
WHERE
  cp.clientId = 1
GROUP BY
  c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.Name, p.productname  FROM Заказ AS z
    INNER JOIN Клиент AS c ON z.clientId = c.id
    INNER JOIN Продукт AS p ON z.productId = p.id
WHERE z.clientId = 1;
```

Выглядеть будет так:

```
|Валера|Хлеб|
|Валера|Соль|
```